# Undefined offset Notice in moodle

Tags: moodle

I am receiving **Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in /var/www/html/lib/tablelib.php on line 1166** . I am clueless about the issue.

I'll be grateful for any help or reference.

Regards

Comment: You should show some code, but this error came when you try to access an array position that doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks found the solution! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove @error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); and @ini_set('display_errors', '1');